# Using hyphen in ansible

Tags: ansible, devops, configuration-management

I am learning Ansible but I am getting confused when to use hyphen and when not to use hyphen in playbook. As I know, hyphen is used for list in Ansible.

For example,

```
--- # my first playbook
      - hosts: webservers  ( why did we use hyphen here it is not a list)
        tasks: 
          - name: installing httpd
            yum: name=httpd state=installed ( why we shouldn't use hyphen here).
```

From Ansible documentation, it is said that hyphen is for list, for example:

```
fruits:
  - apple
  - grapes
  - orange
```

So, I am confused when to use hyphens and when not to use.

Comment: _why did we use hyphen here it is not a list_  Yes, it is a list. A list of plays (only one play in that list, though).

Comment: Exactly. A playbook can have multiple plays. But even if you only have one play defined, it still is a list of plays.

Answer (score 10):

Hyphen `-` is used to specify list items, and colon `:` is used to specify dictionary items or key-value pair. I think a comparable example with another language (e.g. Python) will make this clear. Let's say you have a list `my_list` like this:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

In Ansible you will specify this list items with hyphen:

```
my_list:
  - foo
  - bar
```

Now let's say you have a key-value pair or dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'key_foo': 'value_foo', 
    'key_bar': 'value_bar'
}
```

In Ansible, you will use colon instead of hyphen for key-value pair or dictionary:

```
my_dict:
  key_foo: value_foo
  key_bar: value_bar
```

Inside a playbook you have a list of plays and inside each play you have a list of tasks. Since `tasks` is a list, each task item is started with a hyphen like this:

```
tasks:
  - task_1

  - task_2
```

Now each task itself is a dictionary or key value pair. Your example task contains two keys, `name` and `yum`. `yum` itself is another dictionary with keys `name`, `state` etc.

So to specify task list you use hyphen, but since every task is dictionary they contain colon.

Comment: A small correction: a playbook is composed of one or more plays, not tasks, in a list.

Comment: @PasiH thanks for the correction. I have edited the answer a little to reflect your point.

Answer (score 1):

Any hyphen indicates a new item in a list, as is the case in "- hosts: webservers".
Any item without a hypen belongs to its parent item that prefix with hypen. That's to say "yum: name=httpd state=installed" belongs to "- name" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this equivalent python syntax if i convert above playbook?

```
[ hosts,
        tasks:[
                name,{ yum: { 
                                name:httpd, state:installed
                                }   
                        }   
                ]   
]
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.