# Ansible with_dict expects a dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I know this question has been asked many times before but I must be missing something here!

This is a minimal playbook to reproduce the issue.

Here is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    zones_hash:
      location1:
        id: 1
        control_prefix: '10.1.254'
        data_prefix: '10.1.100'
      location2:
        id: 2
        control_prefix: '10.2.254'
        data_prefix: '10.2.100'
  tasks:
    - name: "test1"
      debug: var="zones_hash"

    - name: "test2"
      debug: var="item"
      with_dict:
      - "{{ zones_hash }}"
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
  config file = /home/configs/_ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************

TASK [test1] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "zones_hash": {
        "location1": {
            "control_prefix": "10.1.254",
            "data_prefix": "10.1.100",
            "id": 1
        },
        "location2": {
            "control_prefix": "10.2.254",
            "data_prefix": "10.2.100",
            "id": 2
        }
    }
}

TASK [test2] ***********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I would expect the item variable printed in task2 to contain (for example):

```
key: location1
value: {
  id: 1
  control_prefix: '10.1.254'
  data_prefix: '10.1.100'
}
```

What are we missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Ansible's documentation needs updated or you've found a bug.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes uses your `with_dict` syntax but it seems like that doesn't work anymore.  The dictionary needs to be on the same line as `with_dict`.

```
- name: "test2"
  debug: var="item"
  with_dict: "{{ zones_hash }}"
```

Comment: It's a documentation bug - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17636.

Answer (score 5):

```
with_dict:
  - "{{ zones_hash }}"
```

declares a **list** with a dict as the first index, and Ansible rightfully complains since it expects a dict.

The solution kfreezy mentioned works since it actually gives a dictionary to `with_dict` and not a list:

```
with_dict: "{{ zones_hash }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is already answered, however I have solved my problem another way. It might be helpful for others.

Name of the dictionary could be a problem also. I named my dictionary name `hdfs_dirs`, and I was seeing `with_dict expects a dict` error. Apparently the same name is defined in the common vars and using the same name is not okay.

When I changed the dictionary name to `hdfs_paths`, it worked.

Double check the name of your dictionary also.:)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is more about YAML syntax!

Actually, a dash/hyphen indicates that what follows is an item of a list. So when you write `- "{{ zones_hash }}"`, you have a '*list of dict*' (with only one item) and not a '*dict*'.

To provide your '*dict*', here is what you need to write:

```
with_dict: 
  "{{ zones_hash }}"
```

Either on one or two lines, it's the absence of the dash that matters (not like it has been said in an other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378696/4842717)).

When you start with Ansible and you are not familiar with YAML, it's not always easy to understand when you need to start your declaration with a dash/hyphen. You have some explanation oriented on that topic [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893726/4842717).

Another good trick to help you to understand and visualize the difference is to convert your YAML code in JSON. Here is a tool to do that:

- https://www.json2yaml.com/